# Abstract Classes, Inheritance and Factory Method in Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, factory

I am confused about the right approach I should take
I am creating a sort of game and in this game the main character has accessories.

So I was thinking about an abstract class named Item. Inheriting from Item are also abstract class such as Glasses, Shirt etc... 
The reason I think it should be abstract is that I never create glasses for example, I create an instance of "Green Shades". Green Shades is also a class and I think it should inherit from glasses of course.
I was thinking about making Item an abstract class and also Glasses an abstract class for example but they have a factory method that generates the types of glasses(Green Shades, Blue Shades and so on).

Each Item has a worth property (basic or rare).
I've started to write something but I am getting confused on the implementation details.

Item:

```
from enum import Enum
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Worth(Enum):
    BASIC = 0
    RARE = 1

class Item(object):
    __metaclas__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, worth):
        self.worth = worth

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def type_factory(self,type):
        pass
```

Glasses and an example of a glasses:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
import importlib
Enums = importlib.import_module('Enums')
Item = importlib.import_module('Item')

class Glasses(Item):
    __metaclas__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self,worth,type):
        super().__init__(worth)
       # self.type = self.type_factory()

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def type_factory(self,type):
        if type == Enums.GlassesType.BLACK_SHADES:
            return BlackShades()
        # so on..

class BlackShades(Glasses):
    def __init__(self,worth):
        super().__init__(worth)
```

What would be the best way to do it? Is there a better example of a factory I should use? Maybe it will be better to use type class creation?

To clarify: I am not looking just to improve this code. I wouldn't mind implementing it from scratch using the right way to do so, which I am not sure what it is due to my lack of experience in Python.

Thanks

Comment: Are you planning on making multiple separate instances of `BlackShades`? Is there a difference in behaviour between `BlackShades` and `GreenShades` or is it just simple attributes like worth and colour?

Comment: There is no need to use importlib in that Case. You could use normal or relative imports

Comment: No major differences will be between them. Only worth an colour

Comment: Add it is called `__metaclass__` with two s. Having said that why are you using Python 2? If you are new to Python you should learn Python 3

Comment: I'm using python 3 but I'm new to python as a whole. Did I use obsolete methods?